# delete from sql with a delete.php file

Tags: php, sql

i am wanting to build a delete page to use to delete some data from my database.

when i put the id in it works fine but i am wanting it to pull the id from the url

www.example.com/delete.php?id=1234

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'DELETE FROM MYTABLE
        WHERE created=<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>';

mysql_select_db('ely');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not delete data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Deleted data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

the part im having issues with is this part

```
 WHERE created=<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>';
```

the error i am getting is "Could not delete data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=' at line 2"

Comment: First, NEVER use unchecked variables from user input. Second, when joining strings you don't have to use `echo`. Third, `mysql_*` is deprecated, use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: Some times I wish to give +100... what this guy said ^^

Comment: One more advice, when you're deleting one row, add `LIMIT 1`. Sometimes it can save your data (I know something about that ;) ).

Comment: you can  use $_REQUEST["id"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$sql = "DELETE FROM MYTABLE
        WHERE created='$id'";

mysql_select_db('ely');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not delete data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Deleted data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Prefer `intval` over `mysql_real_escape_string` for a numeric ID.

Comment: thanks :) this has been giving me a headache for a while now :)

Comment: @Kolink i don't know that id is numeric

Answer (score 0):

learn quoting!

```
  $sql = 'DELETE FROM MYTABLE
       WHERE created=<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>';

  $sql = 'Delete from MYTABLE WHERE created="'.$_GET['id'].'"';
```

Next thing is, google for sql-injections, and keep in mind that you should proof if $_GET['id'] is set in time

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate a variable into a string, use the [concatenation operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

But your code is bad for severalreasons.

1: Sanitise your inputs

[image: xkcd]

2: Don't use GET for anything that can change the state of the server, use POST instead.

[Here's a story explaining one reason why](http://blog.mischel.com/2008/08/08/hey-you-deleted-my-files/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = 'DELETE FROM MYTABLE
        WHERE created=' .$id;
```

"." is used to concatenate the value of the variable $id

As for connecting to a db i suggest you to look up for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="DELETE FROM MYTABLE WHERE created='".$_GET['id']."'";
```